# python3 urllib.request посмотреть, что отправляет в запросе клиент

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

[Попытался повторить пример по ссылке](https://diveintopython3.net/http-web-services.html#whats-on-the-wire)

```
from http.client import HTTPConnection
HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
from urllib.request import urlopen
response = urlopen('https://python.org')
print(response.headers.as_string())
```

Ожидаемый результат должен был включать то, что отправляется в GET запросе, но показывает только заголовок от сервера: print(response.headers.as_string())
[Ответ в этом примере тоже не помог.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789856/turning-on-debug-output-for-python-3-urllib) Не подскажете, можно ли сделать, чтобы был вывод, как в примере по ссылке на diveintopython3? Версия интерпретатора - Python 3.9.2, если это имеет значение.
Ожидаемый результат:

```
send: b'GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: python.org
Accept-Encoding: identity                                       
User-Agent: Python-urllib/3.9
и т.д
...
Connection: close
Content-Length: 50793
Server: nginx
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
и т.д.
```

Выводится только вторая часть

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы удалили тему, я не успел там написать. Пишу здесь. В sqlite нет так называемых sequence. В некоторых других СУБД они есть. Можете попробовать, как написано здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15104932/5045688